# aqueduct db upgrade cannot connect to database

Tags: postgresql, dart, aqueduct

I have problem with connecting my aqueduct server to postgres database.
Informations and things i have done:

- postgres version is **13.0**
- system is Windows 10
- I am using AndroidStudio and internal terminal
- aqueduct version is **3.3.0+1**
- created migration files using `aqueduct db generate`
- I am able to connect to database using psql shell
- created user `lit_test_user`
- created database 'lit_test' and `GRANTED ALL ON lit_test_user`

In `postgresql.conf` set

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
```

In `pg_hba.conf` added lines

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5
```

Now I want to connect to my database with command:

```
aqueduct db upgrade --connect postgres://lit_test_user:czinczolada123@localhost:5432/lit_test
```

Error I get is: `There was an error connecting to the database 'lit_test_user:czinczolada123@localhost:5432/lit_test'. Reason: unable to connect to database.`
I don't know what I did wrong, because using psql shell connects just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rolled back the version of **PostgreSQL to 10.14**. It's stable.

**And `pubspec.yaml` I changed to this:**

```
dependencies:
  aqueduct: ^4.0.0-b1

dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.0.0
  aqueduct_test: ^2.0.0-b1
```

**BUT IMPORTANT.** Enter the command: pub global activate aqueduct 4.0.0-b1